# Дублируется значение в мультиселекте при отправке формы

Tags: yii, http, request, select2

Есть форма на Yii 1.1, в ней мультиселект, каждый раз при отправке формы на сервер, выбранные значения в форме дублируются.

View:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                'id' => 'PersonnelInput-form',
                'method' => 'get',
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'class'=>'form-horizontal',
                ),
                'enableClientValidation' => true,
                'clientOptions' => array(
                    'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                    'afterValidate' => 'js:function(f,d,e) {
            if (e) $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#PersonnelInput-form").offset().top - 50}, 1000);
            return true;
        }',
                ),
            ));
<div class="control-group form-group">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'roles', array('class'=>'control-label col-md-4')); ?>
                <div class="controls col-md-4">
                    <?php echo $form->dropdownList($model, 'roles',
                        ListDataHelper::getAttributeList($employee, false, 'system_role'),
                        array(
                            'class' => 'select2',
                            'style' => 'width: 100%;',
                            'placeholder' => 'Select value',
                            'multiple' => true,
                        )
                    ); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'roles', array('class' => 'help-inline error')); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionPersonnelInput() // TODO: Fix roles input!
{
    $form = new PersonnelInputForm();

    $au_data = $percent = array();
    $au_finished = $su_finished = null;

    if (isset($_GET['PersonnelInputForm'])) {
        $form->attributes = $_GET['PersonnelInputForm'];

        if ($form->validate()) {
            $au_data = Employee::aucasuChartData($form);
            $percent = Employee::percentInputChartData($form);

            $au_finished = Employee::auFinished($form);
            $su_finished = Employee::suFinished($form);
        }
    }

    $this->render('personnelInput', array(
        'au_data' => $au_data,
        'au_finished' => $au_finished,
        'su_finished' => $su_finished,
        'percent' => $percent,
        'model' => $form,
        'monthhr' => date('F, Y', mktime(0,0,0, $form->month, 1, $form->year)),
    ));
}
```

var_dump:
[image: var_dump]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что при отправке формы GET запросом, при повторной отправке берутся данные не только из формы но и из URL'а, поэтому значения дублируются.